# what is the practical meaning of impulse response in frequency domain (Z transformation)?

Tags: math, filter, transformation

I'm trying to understand how impulse response works in frequency domain. I mean we usually use Z transformation to convert signal from time domain to frequency domain, but I wonder is there any practical meaning or example about how it works?

I found a helpful explanation about impulse response here: 
[what is practical meaning of impulse response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17189530/what-is-practical-meaning-of-impulse-response)

can anyone help to explain my question like that?

Comment: Do you have a specific issue related to implementing this in C or Java?

Answer (score 1):

The impulse response, regardless of the domain (spatial, temporal/time, frequency, Z, etc) is effectively the transfer function for a system.

Consider, in the time domain, a signal, f(t), going through a black box system with an impulse response (aka, transfer function), of h(t) for the system. If you take the convolution of the two signals, `f(t)⊗h(t)`, you get a resulting output signal `g(t)=f(t)⊗h(t)`. In the time domain, the impulse response **of the system** is simply `h(t)`. In the frequency domain, if we apply simple Fourier transformation rules:

```
g(t)=f(t)⊗h(t)   <=F=> G(f)=F(f)H(f)
```

In the frequency domain, the impulse function **of the system** is just `H(f)`. It is sometimes also referred to as the "Dirac Delta Response" (ie: how does the system respond if we just apply a brief minimal "pulse" to the input terminal, meaning `f(t)=δ(t)` in the time domain, or `F(f)=1` in the frequency domain).

If you want some further examples, you should check out a list of Fourier transform pairs, as they'll show you what various functions equate to in the time and frequency domain.

Good luck!

**References**

---

1. *Table of Fourier Transform Pairs*, Accessed 2014-03-27, [`<http://uspas.fnal.gov/materials/11ODU/FourierTransformPairs.pdf>`](http://uspas.fnal.gov/materials/11ODU/FourierTransformPairs.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Some of the Fourier Transform pairs, in graphical form.

Square Pulse - time domain (pulse duration is 10% of the sample frame):

[image: Square Pulse in the time domain - Sooeet.com FFT calculator]

Square Pulse FT pair is a sinc function:

[image: Square Pulse in the frequency domain - Sooeet.com FFT calculator]

Sinc function - time domain (16 cycles):

[image: Sinc function in the time domain - Sooeet.com FFT calculator]

Sinc function FT pair is a square pulse:

[image: Sinc function in the frequency domain - Sooeet.com FFT calculator]

Sinc squared function - time domain (8 cycles):

[image: Sinc squared function in the time domain - Sooeet.com FFT calculator]

Sinc squared function FT pair is a triangle function:

[image: Sinc squared function in the frequency domain - Sooeet.com FFT calculator]

Gaussian function - time domain (width 16 samples):

[image: Gaussian function in the time domain - Sooeet.com FFT calculator]

Gaussian function FT pair is another Gaussian:

[image: Gaussian function in the frequency domain - Sooeet.com FFT calculator]

Exponential decay function - time domain (a = 1/64):

[image: Exponential decay function in the time domain - Sooeet.com FFT calculator]

Exponential decay function FT pair is a Lorentzian:

[image: Exponential decay function in the time domain - Sooeet.com FFT calculator]

Triangle function - time domain (width 66 samples):

[image: Triangle function in the time domain - Sooeet.com FFT calculator]

Triangle function FT pair is a sinc squared function:

[image: Triangle function in the frequency domain - Sooeet.com FFT calculator]

Dirac delta function - time domain (a = 1/2^30):

[image: Dirac delta in the time domain - Sooeet.com FFT calculator]

Dirac delta function FT pair is a constant function:

[image: Dirac delta in the frequency domain - Sooeet.com FFT calculator]

Constant function - time domain (y = 1):

[image: Constant function in the time domain - Sooeet.com FFT calculator]

Constant function FT pair is a Dirac delta function:

[image: Constant function in the frequency domain - Sooeet.com FFT calculator]

Graphs and Fourier Transform pairs from the [Sooeet FFT calculator](https://sooeet.com/math/online-fft-calculator.php)

Answer (score 0):

Dirac delta response gives you the [Green's function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function) for the system.  This is the starting point for [boundary element methods](http://www.boundary-element-method.com/).